# NZT On filename output in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We're attempting to send a file to a system (that's very rigid) from our Datafactory with the New Zealand datetime in the filename (ADF are all UTC)

My output dataset looks like this:

```
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "MasterFile-{fileDateNameVariable}.csv",
        "folderPath": "something",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "nullValue": "",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true
        },
        "partitionedBy": [
            {
                "name": "fileDateNameVariable",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "$$addhours(SliceStart, 13)",
                    "format": "yyyyMMdd"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

As you can see I've tried to add in "$$addhours(SliceStart, 13)" but to no avail:

```
Input is malformed. Reason: inputTable.typeProperties : The date $$addhours(SliceStart, 13) is not a valid variable to partition by. Valid values are SliceStart and SliceEnd..
```

Is there a way in which I can create a time variable in the filename without referencing the partitionedBy area?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADFv2, you can use @pipeline.TriggerTime to get the same result without using PartitionedBy.

But it looks like a ADFv1 json, so it should look like this:

```
"typeProperties": {
    "fileName": "MasterFile-{Time.AddHours(fileDateNameVariable,13)}.csv",
    "folderPath": "something",
    "format": {
        "type": "TextFormat",
        "columnDelimiter": ",",
        "nullValue": "",
        "firstRowAsHeader": true
    },
    "partitionedBy": [
        {
            "name": "fileDateNameVariable",
            "value": {
                "type": "DateTime",
                "date": "SliceStart",
                "format": "yyyyMMdd"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe this won't work as-is, I can't test it right now, but that is the correct way to call a function.

Always check here to use functions and system variables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-functions-variables

Hope this helped!

Comment: Unfortuntely it's the same error: Input is malformed. Reason: inputTable.typeProperties : The date Time.AddHours(SliceStart,13) is not a valid variable to partition by. Valid values are SliceStart and SliceEnd.

Comment: Just edited my answer, try with that. If that doesnt work, try adding $$ but that should work.

Comment: Cool, it seems to validate OK, I'll do quick test to ensure it works.

Comment: My only issue to is adding hours to a yyyyMMdd may not work.. that problem should easily be solved outside of this question though

Comment: Did it work? Its been a while since I've used ADFv1. I think that if adding those 13 hours means its one more day, it should be shown on the dd part.

Comment: Nah it didn't work.. came out as goop.. I'll keep trying today

Comment: Definitely a better option :) it's still in preview, but I've deployed it in production environments and works great.